# How to use information from an API request to interact with a website?

Tags: javascript, api, url, request, response

I'm quite familiar with html and css but absolutely not with Javascript and I probably need Javascript to achieve what I want:

Each friday I'm livestreaming at Hitbox.tv. I've embedded the video player on my website. I would like to display an image stored on my server in front of the video player when I'm offline. I always edit the html page manually to show or hide the image, but it would be nice if it works automatically.

At https://api.hitbox.tv/media/status/masta (masta=channelname) I get a response with information of the live-status of my channel at Hitbox.tv. I believe the type of response is called JSON, but how can I use the value of "media_is_live" to show or hide the image on my server?

I searched for a long time on all kind of forums but didn't find an answer that worked out for me. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should at least post the JSON data and the HTML code that you want to change based on the JSON data. Also how is the JSON provided? It does not really make sense if it is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good thing you can use is something called AJAX. AJAX is a piece of web technology that makes a request to a resource after your page has loaded. In order to do this kind of thing, I use the JQuery AJAX function.

In a script tag, you can do something like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: "https://api.hitbox.tv/media/status/masta",
      success: function(data){
        var img = $('myImageId');
        if(data.media_is_live){
          img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
          img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

The $(document).ready(function() { part means that the code inside will execute once the page has loaded.

This answer could be improved with some more information. I am, of course, guessing what the json object you get looks like. If you can post that, I can help more. Remember to import JQuery before the script above.

Comment: Hey, thanks, that looks like something that could work for me. The response I get by visiting the URL looks like this: `{"media_is_live":"0","media_views":"2"}`. The 0 or 1 behind "media_is_live" should toggle the img.style.visibility.

Comment: So, the above should be in the correct format. Have you tried it out?

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work yet. Here's my code: 

`<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: "https://api.hitbox.tv/media/status/masta",
      success: function(data){
        var img = $('off');
        if(data.media_is_live){
          img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
          img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      }); 
    });
</script>

<a href="latest" class="offline"><img id="off" src="img/stream/Offline_960x600_v4.gif" alt="Offline" /></a>`

Comment: What happens? What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Firefox. Nothing happens, the image won't hide when I'm livestreaming. Any ideas?

Comment: No errors. Do I maybe have to make a link to jQuery because I don't have that?

Comment: Definitely could be, you should see an error message about it though.

Comment: I added the jQuery link to the Googleapis, no errors but still nothing happens.

Comment: Was the Googleapis script before or after the script you posted above?

Comment: I posted the Googleapis script above.

Comment: if you add the "console.log(data.media_is_live);" to the line beneath "var img = $('off');" and the look in the console, what is there?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's solved now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971798/how-to-get-and-use-a-json-parameter-value-from-an-api-request-response

Comment: You are welcome! Could you please give me the tick if you think I helped enough.